# Python: How to turn an IMAGE into a STRING and back?

Tags: python-3.x, string, image, byte, python-imaging-library

I have an **image** like this loaded into a `PIL.Image`:

### [image]

And now I want to turn it into a **python string**, and it should not be binary, how do I do this?
Because when I tried to encode I get the following error:

**My Code:**

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("testImage.jpeg")
string = img.tobytes()
string = string.decode("ascii")
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomschimansky/Desktop/SenderMAIN.py", line 5, in <module>
    string = string.decode("ascii")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When this works I also want to turn the string **back into an image**.

**Other methods** that **also don't worke**d for me:

- Read the image directly from file with `open("file","rb")` and then encode it.
- encode it with the `codecs` library. (`string = codecs.encode(string, "base64"`))
- encode it with the `base64` library (was able to convert it to string but the string looked like this: `///////`. (only slashes))

Thanks for your Answers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert to a string like this:

```
import base64

with open("image.png", "rb") as image:
    b64string = base64.b64encode(image.read())
```

That should give you the same results as if you run this in Terminal:

```
base64 < image.png
```

And you can convert that string back to a PIL Image like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

f = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(b64string))
pilimage = Image.open(f)
```

That should be equivalent to the following in Terminal:

```
base64 -D < "STRING" > recoveredimage.png
```

---

Note that if you are sending this over LoRa, you are better off sending the PNG-encoded version of the file like I am here as it is compressed and will take less time. You could, alternatively, send the expanded out in-memory version of the file but that would be nearly 50% larger. The PNG file is 13kB. The expanded out in-memory version will be 100*60*3, or 18kB.

Comment: But the type is <bytes>, and I can't pass bytes to the LoRa sender.c program. Or do you have experiences with LoRa?

Comment: You can add `.decode(‘ASCII’)` to the end to go from bytes to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, this helped me a lot. It's working for me.