# Determining the amount of processors for the current machine

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, parallel-processing, constexpr

Let's say I want to create a simple Thread Pool as such:

```
#include <thread>
#include <array>

template<std::uint32_t TCount>
class ThreadPool {
public:
    std::array<std::thread, TCount> threads;
};
```

The above is simple enough, not concerned with any "implementation details" of a thread pool. However let's say I would like to default the template parameter to amount of available cores for the machine that this code would be run on...

I could probably use a struct with a `constexpr` function as such:

```
struct CoreCount {
    static const std::uint32_t count;

    constexpr std::uint32_t coreCount() {
         return count;
    }

    const std::uint32_t operator()() {
        return coreCount();
    }
};

const std::uint32_t CoreCount::count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

then use the `constexpr` functor above with the initial template parameter like this:

```
template<uint32_t TCount = CoreCount()()>
class ThreadPool {
public:
    std::array<std::thread, TCount> threads;
};
```

However, after reading [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) from `cppreference` about `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` it states that this is only to be used as a hint and that if it is not well defined it can return `0`.

Is there another or safer way to get something like this to work? The main goal is to be able to determine the amount of `cores` at compile time.

---

*-Edit-*

I had originally asked this because I was trying to use `thread` inside of an `std::array` due to less overhead. In the comments many had stated it is probably better to determine this at runtime; okay so no problem. So that leaves me other options such as `vector`, `list` etc. but if I'm trying to stay with lower overhead I'm now wondering if `queue` or `dequeue` would be a better fit.

However, this still hasn't answered my main question about `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`. Is there another function or method that will actually return the amount of cores on the current machine as opposed to being just a hint?

Comment: This should be trivial by using an external script. On Linux, for example, a trivial script can count the number of CPUs listed in /proc/cpuinfo and write out a `#define` into a header file, that all relevant translation units include. Much easier, and simpler, then trying to contort something entirely with the C++ universe, presuming that it's even possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That sounds great in practice, however I'm working on a Windows machine... but the idea would be to try and keep it as generic as possible.

Comment: Seems like it'd be better to try to figure out the number of cores at runtime, in case it's run on a machine with a different number than the one it was compiled on.

Comment: @PhilM hmm good point, but would there be a way to get a runtime value first, then convert that to a const value in order to instantiate such a template? If not; I could just remove the count from the template and just have it passed to the constructor, however, I wouldn't be able to use `std::array` if that's the case...

Comment: Just seconding what others have said, I can't see how at build time you can determine the number of cores at runtime unless your build environment is aware of the target architecture. In which case it would be best to pass the number of target platform cores as a compile time parameter if you really need that information during the build. Which beg's the question why is it necessary during build time?

Comment: @hhafez The idea I had in mind was to have this template create the amount of threads based on the amount of cores on the system that it is running on, I was trying to use `std::array` and the size of `array` has to be known at compile time...

Comment: I think std::vector with a runtime-based parameter would work just as well; the only real difference would be when the underlying array is allocated.

Comment: Echoing the sentiment of others, the core count of the thing running your binary is a distant, later value that you cannot possibly know at compile time unless _by specification_ your binary must be run with a fixed core count. I think it's worth pointing you at a spiritually similar question I asked a long time ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908256/getting-template-metaprogramming-compile-time-constants-at-runtime. Basically, you can generate a large set of possible compile-time values, then at runtime pick one of them. This has dubious use in your case, though, I reckon.

Comment: @PhilM Yeah I know I could of used `vector` or `list` for that matter, but was trying to use the less overhead of `array`. I wonder if `queue` or `deque` would be a better fit then...

Comment: I may edit this question to make it a little more clear of what I'm really after...

Comment: If you're creating a threadpool and have to deal with parallel communication, synchronization, and context switches, the overhead of a `std::vector` compared to the overhead of a `std::array` should be the least of your worries

Comment: @FrancisCugler `std::vector` is a well-performant and well-optimized container on modern systems.  Whatever overhead you think it has will be negligible in lieu of everything else your app has to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau true, but I was trying to avoid the `dynamic` memory with `vector`...

Comment: `std::vector` is going to outperform a `std::list` (or anything else except a `std::array`) in most things, especially when the number of elements is small. If you are careful and able to avoid reallocations then a `std::vector` should be as fast as an `std::array`.

Comment: @Galik Yeah I know that much... I was thinking of making this a `priorty queue` type Thread Pool, instead of serializing the threads, was thinking of having them spawn and run tasks based on a designated or desired priority...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148090/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28026043/2836621

Comment: Are there any reason to put thread count into template ? What is wrong with constructor, and constructor forwarding  i.e. `fixed_thread_pool(std::size_t thread_count); fixed_thread_pool(): fixed_thread_pool(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())`

Comment: As well as, you can use vector or even raw dynamic array then to store threads. But you'd better use native OS API for thread pools if available i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/thread-pool-api